# How does DWORD time in tagKEYBDINPUT work and when to use it?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-keybdinput):

> The time stamp for the event, in milliseconds. If this parameter is zero, the system will provide its own time stamp.

```
typedef struct tagKEYBDINPUT {
  WORD      wVk;
  WORD      wScan;
  DWORD     dwFlags;
  DWORD     time;
  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
} KEYBDINPUT, *PKEYBDINPUT, *LPKEYBDINPUT;
```

When should I specify `time`? Does it expect a unix time stamp? What happens if system receives input with a time stamp that is in the past? I assumed it could have something to do with keeping input events in correct order because I noticed in my tests that sometimes it *seems* like they are executed out of order.

Comment: The `time` is the number of milliseconds elapsed since the computer started (see `GetTickCount()` and `GetMessageTime()`).  And to answer your question, you should never set the `time` to anything other than 0 in normal situations. Let the OS manage the time for you based on when `SendInput()` is actually called.

Comment: [When you synthesize input with SendInput, you are also synthesizing the timestamp](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121101-00/?p=6193).

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, I knew there was an article about it somewhere, I just couldn't find it

Comment: Thanks, that was a very fun read.

Comment: @miran80 Raymond's blogs is very clear and answers your question. You can 
 answer your own question.